# Many to many query is very slow in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this database with 3 tables, pies, persons and a junction between the two. A pie can be made my many persons, and a person can make many pies, so a very legit usecase.

What I want to output is a massive table, in the following format:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------
| person_id | person_name | pies
+-------------------------------------------------------
|     1     |    john     | apple, banana, plum, ..
|     2     |    mary     | apple, plum, pineapple, ..
|    ...    |     ...     | ..., ..., ..., ...
|   10000   |    josh     | banana, coconut, ...
```

I am currently achieving this as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import random
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

person_to_pie_association_table = db.Table(
    'person_to_pie_association_table',
    db.metadata,
    db.Column('pie_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pie.id')),
    db.Column('person_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
)

class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    pies = db.relationship("Pie", secondary=person_to_pie_association_table, backref="pies")


class Pie(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pie'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    flavour = db.Column(db.String)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

db.create_all()

for i in range(1, 10000):
    name = random.choice(['mary', 'mr F', 'harry', 'cathy', 'john']) + str(i)
    person = Person(name=name)
    flavour = random.choice(['banana', 'strawberry', 'apple', 'chocolate']) + str(i)
    pie = Pie(flavour=flavour)
    db.session.add(person)
    db.session.add(pie)
db.session.commit()

pielist = Pie.query.all()

for i in range(1, 10000):
    print(i)
    person = Person.query.get(i)
    person.pies = random.sample(pielist, 5)
    db.session.add(person)
db.session.commit()

persons = Person.query.all()
start = time.time()
for person in persons:
    person.name
middle = time.time()
for person in persons:
    person.pieflavours = ', '.join([pie.flavour for pie in person.pies])
end = time.time()
print(middle - start)  # 0.005s
print(end - middle)  # 38s
```

However, it's pretty slow. I think this is because `person.pies` is only executed once it's referenced, and it executes a SQL query, which makes 10.000 queries in total. I've been going through the SQLAlchemy documentation and other SO questions, but couldn't find a satisfactory answer on how to deal with this.

So instead of joining on the go, it should be joined beforehand. I tried formulating the query like this as well: `Person.query.join(Pie, Person.pies)`, but the results where the same.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I didn't look well enough after all, setting the `lazy` argument of the relationship to `'joined'` made it 1000x faster (literally).

```
    pies = db.relationship("Pie", secondary=person_to_pie_association_table, backref="pies", lazy='joined')
```